# Java ROI Compound Calculator

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, recursion

I have been trying to make a program that takes in:

1. Initial Value (in billions)
2. Growth Rate / Year (in billions)
3. Purchase Price (in billions)

And then is able to calculate the number of years it would take to break even on the investment. I have been able to accomplish this with a brute force algorithm.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this more efficiently (in a way that is more similar to standard algebra).

My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReturnOnInvestment {
  public static double initialValue;
  public static double growthRate;
  public static double purchasePrice;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println("     Return on Investment Calculator     ");
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    System.out.print(" Starting Value (In Billions): ");
    initialValue = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print(" Growth Rate (Per Year in Billions): ");
    growthRate = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print(" Purchase Price (In Billions): ");
    purchasePrice = input.nextDouble();
    input.close();

    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(" ROI Period: " + calculateYears(0) + " Years");
  }

  public static double calculateMoney(double years) {
    if(years < 1) return 0;
    return calculateMoney(years - 1) + initialValue + (growthRate * (years - 1)); 
  }

  public static double calculateYears(double years) {
    if(calculateMoney(years) >= purchasePrice) return Math.round(years * 100) / 100.0;
    return calculateYears(years + 0.01);
  }

}
```

Comment: Use `for` loops instead of recursion.

Comment: No need - you can do it without any loops at all with a bit of maths.

Comment: @EricLeus Note: a growth rate isn't "in billions" like you are saying to the user. 5% growth per year means a rate of 0.05 growth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can use the logarithm function for that.

Given your Java code you can write:

```
public static double yearsNeeded(double initialValue, double growthRate, double purchasePrice) {
    return Math.log(purchasePrice / initialValue) / Math.log(1 + growthRate);
}
```

with an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Years to go from 100 to 150 with a growth rate of 5%: "
            + yearsNeeded(100, .05, 150));
}
```

Basically you're trying to solve for "years":

```
initialValue * (1 + growthRate) ^ years = purchasePrice
```

where ^ means exponentiation.

You can rewrite that to:

```
(1 + growthRate) ^ years = purchasePrice / initialValue
```

which turns into:

```
years = [1 + growthRate] log (purchasePrice / initialValue)
```

where the base of the log is "1 + growthRate". And a log of another base is the same as the log in any base divided by the log of the base.

Comment: Thank you, I was also wondering how you would do this with compounding the initial price on top of the value. Example: Year 1: 50 Year 2 50*2 + growthRate Year 3: 50*3 + growthRate * 2

Comment: I'd think you can set the growth rate 1 higher. If the growth rate is 5%, and the initialValue is 1, you'd get 1 * (1 + .05) = 1.05 after a year. If you want to also double the initialValue you can use a growth rate of 105% = 1.05: 1 * (1 + 1.05) = 1*2.05 = 2.05

Comment: I tried that, but yearsNeeded(50, 0.05, 1000) returned 4.17 years and that is obviously not right.

Comment: You must have missed a zero - `yearsNeeded(100, .05, 1000)` gives `47.19363281906435`. And `100 * Math.pow(1 + .05, 47.19363281906435)` gives 1000.

Comment: One problem is that it does not take 47 years to get 1000, even without the growth rate it should take 10 years (1000 / 100).

Comment: Without a growth rate your initial value stays the same forever. To multiply your initial value by 10 in 10 years you need a growth rate of 25.89%